# How does np.array() works internally?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I've written my own [tensor library](https://github.com/etaler/Etaler) and a corresponding [Python binding](https://github.com/etaler/PyEtaler). And I've made sure iterating through my tensor implementation works exactly like how NumPy works. I also made sure important method calls like `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, etc... all works like how NumPy expected it to be. And so I expect

```py
t = my_tensor.ones((4, 4))
print(t) # works
a = np.array(t)
print(a) # becomes a 32 dimension array
```

to give me a 4x4 matrix. But instead it gave me a 4x4x1x1.... (32 dims in total) array. I'm out of ways to debug this problem without knowing how NumPy performs the conversion internally. How does `np.array` works internally? I'm unable to locate the function within NumPy's source code nor I can find useful information on the web.

Comment: What's the `dtype'?   32 is the max number of dimensions.  `np.array` is compiled function on the numpy github.  The `c` source is hard to follow.

Comment: The dtype returns a enum (due to restrictions on the C++ side). And the actual type inside my tensors are python native types (or `cppyy` types if no direct match avalable)

Comment: The max number of trailing 1s suggests that `array` has hit some sort of recursive sequence definition at the lowest level.  After deducing that it has a sequence of len 4, each being a sequence of 4, it then 'asks' what those elements are.  And they apparently are some sort of self referencing object.  It sees a recursive sequence of size 1.

Comment: What's `t[0,0,0]` or `t[0][0][0]`?

Comment: @hpaulj Ahhhhh....!! That's the problem. `t[0][0][0]` returns `1` because I made it so there's no 0D tensors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the official Numpy's documentation? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/contents.html

Questions specific as this one are usually solved by looking at the original library documentation (e.g. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#array-creation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I have looked into the documents. But the documents (and the tutorials) only document the behavior of numpy. But I need the internals in this case.